# Delete a file using Swift in iOS

Tags: ios, file, swift3

Consider:

```
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}
```

So simply, I get my filename using that function. And it returns correctly for now. How can I delete this file using Swift 3?
And *how* can I read the image back like `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`?

```
let image_data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.commons.correctlyOrientedImage(image: self.imageSelected.image!), 0.5)
```

I did the following and its not working

```
let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("l.png")
let fileManager = FileManager.default
var filePath = filename
// Check if file exists

if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath.absoluteString) {
    // Delete file
    try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: filePath.absoluteString)
} else {
    print("File does not exist")
}
```

I save the file like this

```
let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("COPY111.PNG")
               try? image_data?.write(to: filename)
```

But I cannot remove it from the answers provided below.

Comment: Since `fileExists(atPath:)` and `removeItem(atPath:)` expect a file path string, change `filePath.absoluteString` to `filePath.path` and then your code will work.

Comment: I strongly recommend not to call variables that contain a url “path”. It only confuses you. Note that URLs are the recommended interface to work wit files, not paths.

Answer (score 40):

There're lines for deleting a file:

```
do {
    try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: fileName)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Error: \(error.domain)")
}
```

And here's code for setting it to imageView:

```
if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: fileName) {
   imageView.image = image
}
```

Comment: The `UIImage` code here won't compile. `fileName` is a `URL` (at least it is must be in the `FileManager removeItem(at:)` code). `UIImage init(contentsOfFile:)` takes a `String`.

Comment: That’s why I’d always advise people to use “url” in the variable name for URLs. So it should be fileURL (which is a bit redundant) or imageURL.

Answer (score 9):

Try this. To **delete a file**:

```
    let fileNameToDelete = "myFileName.txt"
    var filePath = ""

    // Fine documents directory on device
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let documentDirectory = paths[0]
    filePath = documentDirectory.appendingFormat("/" + fileNameToDelete)

    do {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default

        // Check if file exists
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
            // Delete file
            try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: filePath)
        } else {
            print("File does not exist")
        }
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("An error took place: \(error)")
    }
```

Source: *[Delete File Example in Swift](http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/code-examples/delete-file-example-in-swift/)*

For **image loading**:

```
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image)!
let docDir = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
let imageURL = docDir.appendingPathComponent("tmp.jpeg")
try! imageData.write(to: imageURL)

let newImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path)!
```

Comment: I edited my first post, i did ur solution but i get file does nto exist

Comment: i get filepath, but on delete it says  file does not exist filePath
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D5FA0123-65A2-470A-A817-8871F984CE90/Documents/profile-FFCEBEA9-2F8D-49E2-9A09-2BF87BD0B542--A9636AF4-350D-4D72-A4BD-E4F2B183F4BB.png
filePath
File does not exist

Comment: Do NOT use string concatenation to build paths. Use methods to add path components, and use URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath.path) {
    // Delete file
        try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: filePath.path)
}
else {
    print("File does not exist")
}
```

Comment: Re *"put your remove code in DispatchQeue.main.async"*: Why? Why is that an advantage? What is the reasoning?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Hi Peter, you are right, this answer is for the past, I fixed it.

Comment: The update to this question is wrong in the same way the code in the question is wrong. You are now simply repeating the original code. Never use `absoluteString` to convert a `URL` to a path string. Use the `path` property of `URL`. For example, `if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath.path) {`. Also, your answer still mentions the use of `DispatchQeue.main.async`.